# mysql:how to insert into a table with many index faster?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a partition table with about 50 indexs and I will insert about 20 million 
records every day.

Every time I call `insert into tableA values (..),(..)...` to insert 2000 records.this will take about five hours.
I can't load data from file. So I create a table `talbeB` as same as `tableA`, but `tableB` don't have index. First I insert data into `tableB`, then I call `insert into tableA select * from tableB where mydate = 20181119`. the first stage cost about 40 minutes, the second stage about one hour.

I want to know if have a method faster. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `50 indexes?` Show the `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` statement maybe you can drop some??

Comment: Are these in date order? Is tableA's date always less than tableB?

Comment: @RaymondNijland sorry I can not. it involves business secrets

Comment: Just follow MySQL's tips for bulk loading/inserting: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html

Comment: Wow your not leaking out business secrets with a CREATE TABLE statement?

Comment: @danblack data is the same. both of them are partitioned by date.

Comment: i would advice to better configure the temporary table settings because `insert into tableA select * from tableB where mydate = 20181119` can trigger a massive temporary table.. Besides it also can be executes as a disk based temporary table if the memory values are to low to counter that you can mount the mysql temporary files directory location into a disk ram..

Comment: @RaymondNijland tableB is just a temprory table. I just want to first load data from outside at all. and server have many rams and  20million data size is not too large.

Comment: " I can't load data from file." ? Why not you don't have the privilege for it or is the file simply not on the server? And what table engine are you using if you use InnoDB check @TimBiegeleisen comment

Comment: "and server have many rams and 20million data size is not too large." Assuming the MySQL server is configured correctly to also **use** the server ram to the fullest..

Comment: @Raymond Nijland Big companies always have strange permissions issues, and there are various restrictions on access to the machine, including ssh. The mysql cluster machine is not allowed to log in.

Comment: i advice you to move over to [DBA stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) it's more database related so maybe you get this solved over there or advice or boss to hire a DBA.. But without information like `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` statements and or MySQL configuation i doubt DBS stackexchange can help you.

Answer (score 1):

- Don't index flags, or other low-cardinality columns, by themselves.  The Optimizer won't use the index.
- `UNIQUE` indexes are more costly than non-unique ones.  How many of them do you have.
- Batch 100, not 2000 rows at a time in a single `INSERT` statement.
- Is Replication involved?
- Is the table InnoDB?  (MyISAM has lots of other problems, and a few solutions.)
- How much RAM do you have?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?
- What do you mean by "first stage"?
- `PARTITION` by date?  Provide the actual partition definition.  There are good ways to do it and useless ways.
- How many partitions?  More than 50 has performance problems.  Tell me how many, plus provide `SHOW VARIABLES` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS`; there *may* be a workaround if you have too many.
- Will you be purging "old" data?  Is that the reason for partitioning?  If not, then partitioning may be hurting more than helping.
- Do not use RAM disk; it takes away from better uses of RAM.
- How many rows are to be inserted, and how often?  That is, is this an hourly load of 2M rows?  Or a continuous load of 250/second?  Or some other pattern?
- SSD drives?
- This smells like a Data Warehouse.  There are many techniques for such.  The main one is to offload stuff from the Fact table into Summary Tables.  You can probably get rid of *most* of the 50 indexes once you do this.  Furthermore, building a "report" from a Summary table may be 10 times as fast as direct from the Fact table.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for further discussion.  You can obfuscate the column names, but be consistent with the indexes and have the actual datatypes.

DW: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/datawarehouse
Summary Tables:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables
High Speed Ingestion (aimed at 'continuous'): http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table
Partitioning:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint